# Fourier transform of a real white noise on a 3D cubic lattice

Tags: random, fourier-analysis

I'm facing the following problem:
I have a cubic domain of side $L=2\pi$; this domain is divided in a cubic grid, each side is divided in $N$ points, where $N$ is an even integer number.
the coordinates of the grid points are:

$\boldsymbol{x}_{grid}=\frac{2\pi}{N}(i-1,\;j-1\,\;k-1) \; \text{for} \; i,j,k=0, \;N-1$

On each grid point i have a real valued white noise $\eta(\boldsymbol{x}_{grid})$ that is to say an independent standard Gaussian random number on each grid point.

What i want to do is to take the Fourier transform of this three dimensional array $\eta(\boldsymbol{x}_{grid})$ through the Fourier routine in mathematica.

Therefore i define a wavevector grid $\boldsymbol{k}_{grid}$ which is a three dimensional grid in the wavevector space.
the points of this grids are:

$\boldsymbol{k}_{grid}=(i,j,k) \;\;\text{if}\;\; i||j||k \geq 0 \leq N/2$

while if either $i$, $j$ or $k$ are greater than $N/2$ the grid coordinate of  $\boldsymbol{k}_{grid}=$  becomes respectively $i-N$, $j-N$ or $k-N$

in practice the wavevector grid goes from $0$ to $N/2$ then shifts back to $-N/2 +1$ clearly the last element is $-1$.

(for those who are interested i'm following section $5$ of this paper: 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999114001867)

Now i want to look at the properties of the transformed random noise $\hat{\eta}(\boldsymbol{k}_{grid})$.
I would like to know if  what i get is correct because i'm not an expert of discrete fourier transforms.

In the wavevector space i get a random variable which satisfies the property $\hat{\eta}(\boldsymbol{k}_{grid})=\overline{\hat{\eta}(\boldsymbol{-k}_{grid}})$ where the overline refers to the complex conjugate.
Moreover I get that the $\hat{\eta}(0,0,0)$ and $\hat{\eta}(N/2,N/2,N/2)$ are real valued, (i.e. their imaginary part is zero)

Are these properties correct for the Fourier transform of a real noise? Is it also true the vice-versa? (i mean that the inverse fourier transform of a complex noise, which satisfies the above properties in the wavevector space, is a real noise in real space).

I'm also interested in the relationship between the meaning of the transformed value at $\boldsymbol{k}_{grid}=(0,0,0)$ and $\boldsymbol{k}_{grid}=(N/2,N/2,N/2)$

In particular if a the discrete fourier transform of a real valued random process has the property:
$\hat{\eta}(\boldsymbol{k}_{grid})=\overline{\hat{\eta}(\boldsymbol{-k}_{grid}})$
what happens for the points for which one of the index is $N/2$? as there's no $-N/2$ point index in the grid...

Thanks in advance for the answers...

Comment: While I understand that you have used *Mathematica* to compute the DFT, it appears that the question is about the actual mathematics rather than the software. I am voting to move this to the mathematics site. You may also want to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_real-input_DFT).